# Identity SQL Server Notnullexception C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, bindingnavigator

I am looking now for like an hour for a solution for my problem.

I have a SQL Server database table which the script is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] (
    [Id]                      BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name]                    NVARCHAR (100)  NULL, ........
```

With C# I am trying to insert values in my database using a DataGridView which I created automatically with Visual Studio 2012.

Now when I try to insert some value using the binding navigator, I get the `NoNullAllowedException` on the ID. Why? I don't understand why this doesn't work.

I hope you can help me and thank you.

Good Day

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** you might be trying to insert value for `IDENTITY` column.

**Solution :** you should completly omit the value for `IDENTITY` column while inserting the data.

because `IDENTITY` columns willbe inserted by default.

Try This:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(Name)
 Values('somevalue');
```